# Php echo in php inside input tag

Tags: php, input, tags, echo

How can i add this `value="'echo $_SESSION['module'];'"`
to apear value in session

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == "normalUser"){
   echo '<div class="form-group">
 <input required type="text" name="indeks" id="indeks" class="form-
 control input-lg" placeholder="Индекс" value="'echo $_SESSION['module'];'" tabindex="1">
        </div>';
  }?>
```

Comment: You can't `echo` in and `echo`. Concatenate, or close the echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation.

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == "normalUser"){
   echo '<div class="form-group">
 <input required type="text" name="indeks" id="indeks" class="form-
 control input-lg" placeholder="Индекс" value="' . $_SESSION['module'] . '" tabindex="1">
        </div>';
  }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use your HTML outside the PHP as you can like:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['role'] == "normalUser"){
? >
 <div class="form-group">
 <input required type="text" name="indeks" id="indeks"  class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Индекс" 
value="<?=$_SESSION['module'];?>"  tabindex="1">
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```